# Using a reactive value and a reactive expression to trigger an observeEvent

Tags: r, shiny

The module in the app below contains an observer that has two triggers:

1. a reactive value `input$trigger1` (the value of a fileInput that
   is rendered inside the module server)
2. a reactive expression `trigger2()` (the expression returns the value of an actionButton in the main app that is fed to the module).

I would like the observer to print some text to the console when triggered by changes in either of these two values.

**Attempt 1:** I tried wrapping the triggers in a vector:

```
  observeEvent(c(input$trigger1, trigger2()), print('the one with the vector'), ignoreInit = T)
```

Problem: This observeEvent fires when the checkbox is checked.

I thought this might have something to do with the module's server being called instantaneously on app start-up whereas the module's UI is only rendered if `input$check == TRUE`? I tried investigating this by printing the values of `input$trigger1` and `trigger2()` to the console using `observe()`. On start-up, the values printed to the console are `trigger2(): 0` `input$trigger1: NULL`. When the checkbox is checked, `input$trigger1` is still `NULL` but the observer fires again and prints `input$trigger1: NULL` to the console. Maybe this is due to `trigger1` not existing in the DOM on start-up?

So I tried calling both the module's server and UI at the same time like so:

```
output$form = renderUI({req(input$check); modUI('mod')})

observeEvent(input$check, {
    req(input$check)
    callModule(modServer, 'mod', trigger2 = reactive(input$trigger2))
})
```

But the value of `input$trigger1` still gets printed to the console twice, this time when the checkbox is checked. I don't know why because it's `NULL` on both occasions.

---

**Attempt 2:** [According to a post in this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shiny-discuss/vd_nB-BH8sw/Z7IVbubtAwAJ) it occurred to me that since `input$trigger1` and `trigger()` have different classes, wrapping them in a vector might be the source of the problem (since R coerces them to the same class as pointed out by the linked post). So I tried using curly braces instead:

```
  observeEvent({input$trigger1; trigger2()}, print('the one with curly braces'), ignoreInit = T)
```

Problem: This observer responds to changes in `trigger2()` but not to changes in `input$trigger1`. Maybe this has something to do with the return value of the `eventExpr` (`trigger2()`) not changing if `input$trigger1` changes, but since the the `eventExpr` is a reactive expression, a change to either `input$trigger1` or `trigger2()` should invalidate it to trigger the observer as in [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shiny-discuss/vd_nB-BH8sw/n_OWksTBAgAJ).

---

**Attempt 3:** I tried swapping the order of the triggers:

```
  observeEvent({trigger2(); input$trigger1}, print('the one with curly braces with the order swapped around'), ignoreInit = T)
```

Problem: This time the observer responds to both triggers but *only if* input$trigger1 is changed first. Otherwise, it is unresponsive.

---

Here is the reproducible code:

```js
library("shiny")

# MODULE UI ---------------------------------------------------------------
modUI = function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns('ui'))
}

# MODULE SERVER -----------------------------------------------------------
modServer = function(input, output, session, trigger2) {
  
  ns = session$ns
  
  output$ui = renderUI(fileInput(ns('trigger1'), 'Trigger1'))
  
  #OBSERVER 1 ---------------------------------------------
  observeEvent(c(input$trigger1, trigger2()), print('the one with the vector'), ignoreInit = T)

  # observe(print(list(`trigger2 (actionButton)` = trigger2())))
  # observe(print(list(`trigger1 (fileInput)`= input$trigger1)))
  
  #OBSERVER 2 ---------------------------------------------
  # observeEvent({input$trigger1; trigger2()}, print('the one with curly braces'), ignoreInit = T)

  #OBSERVER 3 ---------------------------------------------
  # observeEvent({trigger2(); input$trigger1}, print('the one with curly braces with the order swapped around'), ignoreInit = T)
  
}


# MAIN APP ----------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput('check', 'Show'),
  uiOutput('form'),
  actionButton('trigger2', 'Trigger 2')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  output$form = renderUI({req(input$check); modUI('mod')})
  
  # observe({
  #   req(input$check)
  #   callModule(modServer, 'mod', trigger2 = reactive(input$trigger2))
  # })
  
  callModule(modServer, 'mod', trigger2 = reactive(input$trigger2))
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I've tried everything I can think of to isolate the issue to no avail so any and all guidance would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Maybe it has something to do with the value of `input$file` being a `data.frame`? I tried replacing `input$trigger1` with `trigger1()`, a reactiveVal that increments by 1 each time `input$trigger1` changes. This way both triggers have the same class and length (i.e. numeric(1)). The resulting observer works as expected:

```
modServer = function(input, output, session, trigger2) {

  ns = session$ns

  trigger1 = reactiveVal(0)

  observeEvent(input$trigger1, trigger1(trigger1()+1))

  observeEvent({trigger2(); trigger1()}, print('hello'), ignoreInit = T)

}
```

I would still like to understand why attempts 1-3 didn't work though so if anyone has any insight, please post a reply.

---

**Explanation:** As MattB pointed out, the actionButton initialises as 0 and the fileInput initialises as NULL. This means that the eventExpr for the observers in attempt 2 and 3 will evaluate to NULL as long as the input value on the last line of the expression is NULL. The eventExpr of the example in the linked post consists of a numericInput and a textInput. Since these initialise with values 0 and '' respectively, the eventExpr never returns NULL and the observer is always responsive to both inputs regardless of which is changed first.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the trigger events in a list?

Comment: Thank you Bertil, that almost works! Wrapping the triggers in a list makes the observer responsive to `input$trigger1` and `trigger2()` as desired but it also causes it to fire when the checkbox is checked :( Any idea on why that's happening? Setting `ignoreInit == T` doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`observeEvent` has `ignoreNULL = TRUE` set by default. As you correctly suspect, while the observer will trigger for a change to any part of `{x;y}`, it will only do that if the value of *that whole expression* is not NULL. In this example, as long as `y` is NULL, the observer won't trigger, no matter what you do to `x`. This is easily fixed by setting `ignoreNULL = FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks @MattB, that makes sense but setting `ignoreNULL = TRUE` doesn't make observer 3 responsive to `trigger2()` when `input$trigger1` is `NULL`. What would explain this and observer 2's behaviour?

Comment: Do you mean setting `ignoreNULL = FALSE`?

Comment: +1 Sorry, my bad, I was trying `ignoreNULL = T`. `ignoreNULL == FALSE`. does make all three observers responsive to both triggers but it also makes them fire when the checkbox is checked. Is this because of the way the module's server is called before its UI (since the UI is only called when the checkbox is checked)? I tried calling the module's server when the checkbox is checked (i.e. observeEvent(input$check,{ req(input$check); callModule(modServer, 'mod', trigger2 = reactive(input$trigger2)) })) but it didn't help.

Comment: Can't help with that one I'm afraid. I can't see anything that would cause that (I've not used shiny modules before though).

Comment: No worries, it probably has to to do with how I'm calling/rendering the module in that case. I've accepted your answer since it explains why observer 2 and 3 didn't work. Thank you for your help, I had totally overlooked the fact that the eventExpr for 2 and 3 was returning NULL.